# How do I back up videos using IFTTT, not just photos or is there an alternative?

Tags: ios, backup, software-recommendation, video, automation

I created an IFTTT applet to backup photos from my camera roll to Google Drive, which is syncing to my Mac. I created a folder action to move all files from that Google Drive folder(`~/Google Drive/IFTTT`) to `~/Pictures/IFTTT`. The photos backup fine, but the videos aren't even detected by IFTTT.

How can I get IFTTT to backup all my photos and videos?

If not, **is there an alternative** to back up both my photos and videos? I only want the photos backing up to my Mac, and not the cloud as I already use Google Photos.

Comment: This seems to be a limitation with IFTTT.

Comment: So the IFTTT applet copies your photos in the iOS Camera Roll to Google Drive (1), Google Drive to Google Drive for macOS (2) and from folder A to folder B using a macOS folder action (3). Is that correct?

Comment: @oa- Yes, that is correct

Comment: Thanks. Which of these three steps does not copy the videos? iOS Camera Roll to Google Drive?

Comment: @oa- Yeah, IFTTT doesn't copy the videos from the iOS Camera Roll to Google Drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IFTTT does not support videos with [iOS Photos](https://ifttt.com/ios_photos).

You can, however, use Dropbox for iOS on your iOS device and enable Camera Uploads (Dropbox > Settings > Camera Uploads).